# Возможно ли нарисовать форму логотипа на css?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что непонятно как сделать подобные закругления наружу, которые выделены на картинке.
Сам полукруг можно сделать как отдельным блоком, так и псевдоэлементом.
Пробовал сделать эти закругления через псевдоэлементы, голову сломал.

Comment: Не совсем понятно про какие именно полукруги вы говорите. Если имеется в виду низ черепицы, то думаю стоит посмотреть на [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) и [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image). Так же можно попрбовать отрисовать лого в svg, а не пытаться сверстать.

Comment: @Ein исправил вопрос, надеюсь теперь суть понятна

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как комментирует **@Ein**

> Так же можно попробовать отрисовать лого в svg, а не пытаться
> сверстать.

Действительно проще любую фигуру со сложными кривыми нарисовать в векторном редакторе.
Для этого:

1. Загрузите растровую картинку в векторный редактор, например Inkscape
2. По контуру фигуры нанесите узловые точки с помощью инструмента "Рисовать кривые Безье"
3. Перемещением рычагов управления узловых точек, добейтесь полного совпадения контуров рисунка и кривых линий
4. Сохраните файл в формате `*.svg`
5. Оптимизируйте код с помощью [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

```css
.container {
width:80vw;
height:80vh;
}
svg {
background:#f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 898 470" >

  <path d="M10 9v310c0 107 343 152 357 129 13-21 42-49 69-48 40 0 54 31 77 50 20 17 344-10 349-131V9Z" fill="white" stroke="none"/>
</svg>
</div>
```